# Foundation 5+ Accordion does not work inside Equalizer columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

If you try to place an accordion inside an equalized column, the accordion content will flow over the elements below it rather than pushing them down. 
This is because the elements in the accordion are hidden initially and equalizer cannot calculate it's correct height [on the fly]

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this little quirk?